# UIVideoEditorController keeps cancelling instead of saving

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-editing, uivideoeditorcontroller

I have set up UIVideoEditorController as followed

```
if UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideo(atPath: video.path) {
    let editController = UIVideoEditorController()
    editController.videoPath = video.path
    editController.delegate = self
    present(editController, animated:true)
}
```

It will end up in the cancel delegate call and then dismisses the editor

```
    func videoEditorControllerDidCancel(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController) {
        print("in here")
        editor.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Does anyone know why this is or if I need additional configurations to get it to work?

Comment: I'm facing this same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: same thing with my code. Did u got the solution ??

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Comment: Did you happen to ever figure out a solution? I'm banging my head against a wall and no one seems to be talking about it anywhere else.